# Python regex to extract version from a string

Tags: python, regex

The string looks like this: (`\n` used to break the line)

```
MySQL-vm
Version 1.0.1

WARNING:: NEVER EDIT/DELETE THIS SECTION
```

What I want is only 1.0.1 .

I am trying `re.search(r"Version+'([^']*)'", my_string, re.M).group(1)` but it is not working.

`re.findall(r'\d+', version)` is giving me an array of the numbers which again I have to append.

How can I improve the regex ?

Comment: I would suggest to first parse the string and apply the regex only on relevant parts. Will make your life easier.

Comment: `"Version+"` means match `V-e-r-s-i-o` and then one or more `n`s.

Comment: it repeats only the `n` one or more times.

Comment: Look closely at the attempt, `re.search(r"Version+'([^']*)'", my_string, re.M).group(1)`. What is the intended purpose of the `'`s? Based on how it is constructed, it looks as though you are quite deliberately looking for a single-quoted string (i.e.: a single-quote, some not-single-quote characters, and then a closing single-quote). Now, look carefully at the input: *does the data you want actually look like that*? I don't see quotes around the `1.0.1`, therefore there is no reason to look for them. Why was this not closed as an obvious typo at the time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the version number from group index 1.

```
Version\s*([\d.]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aB2vZ7/5)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """MySQL-vm
... Version 1.0.1
... 
... WARNING:: NEVER EDIT/DELETE THIS SECTION"""
>>> re.search(r'Version\s*([\d.]+)', s).group(1)
'1.0.1'
```

**Explanation:**

```
Version                  'Version'
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
(                        group and capture to \1:
  [\d.]+                   any character of: digits (0-9), '.' (1
                           or more times)
)                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the python `re` library.
The regex described is for versions containing numbers only.

```py
import re

versions = re.findall('[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*', AVAILABLE_VERSIONS)

unique_versions = set(versions) # convert it to set to get unique versions
```

Where
`AVAILABLE_VERSIONS` is string containing versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Positive Look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as well that do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not. In below regex you don't need to `findAll` and `group` functions.

```
(?<=Version )[\d.]+
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lX9nJ9/1)

Explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    Version                  'Version '
  )                        end of look-behind
  [\d.]+                   any character of: digits (0-9), '.' (1 or more times)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=Version\s)\S+
```

Try this.Use this with `re.findall`.

```
x="""MySQL-vm
  Version 1.0.1

  WARNING:: NEVER EDIT/DELETE THIS SECTION"""

print re.findall(r"(?<=Version\s)\S+",x)
```

Output:['1.0.1']

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/12

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/5Us6ow/1

Bit recursive to match versions like 1, 1.0, 1.0.1:

```
def version_parser(v):
    versionPattern = r'\d+(=?\.(\d+(=?\.(\d+)*)*)*)*'
    regexMatcher = re.compile(versionPattern)
    return regexMatcher.search(v).group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but none of the answers cover corner cases such as `Version 1.2.3.` (ending with dot) or `Version 1.2.3.A` (ending with non-numeric values)
Here is my solution:

```
ver = "Version 1.2.3.9\nWarning blah blah..."
print(bool(re.match("Version\s*[\d\.]+\d", ver)))
```